# How to organize a List of Free Resources in the conxtext of PSE

Tags: discussion, best-practices

This very useful question (community wiki) [list-of-freely-available-physics-books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/list-of-freely-available-physics-books) is 
collecting a list of freely available resources that we find out there.
How to make it more organized, without transfer the work to some specific individual ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to make it more organized

If it is community wiki, then just actively encourage everyone to edit it -- **make sure the post itself prominently says "please edit me to make me better!"**

We also support anonymous peer reviewed edits as well:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Answer (score 1):

If we are really going to make a list of all the free physics books out there, including things like readable sets of lecture notes, it will get unwieldy.  We might want to start separate threads for separate areas of physics and link them to each other.

Comment: We could do this in one thread by using separate answers per area and turn the "question" into a table of content linking to the "answers". Something similar to [the community FAQ @ meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)